# Any concurrent maps with better performance than ConcurrentHashMap?

Tags: java, concurrency, dictionary, concurrenthashmap

I understand that `ConcurrentHashMap`  implements the backing table as multiple segment arrays rather than a single array to improve concurrent access performance.  Are there any other `Map` implementations in java that've better performance in a concurrent environment than `ConcurrentHashMap`?

Comment: Do you have reasons to believe that `ConcurrentHashMap` is the source of your performance problems?  Has a profiler showed you that it is a problem?

Comment: Also note that the performance has improved with every version of Java since it was first introduced. And I think I've read that Java 8 performance of CHM is better than with Java 7 (can't find reference right now).

Comment: you need a benchmark reflecting your usage patterns to find out for sure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [ConcurrentSkipListMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedDeque.html) is more tolerant of extremely high volume changes than a ConcurrentHashMap, but its amortized lookup time is O(log(n)) rather than O(1).

So, as with all data structures, "best performance" depends on your usage pattern and definition of "performance."

Comment: Do you have reasons to believe that ConcurrentSkipListMap has better Map performance compared to CHM?

Comment: No definition of "Map Performance" has been provided, so it is impossible to say, as I indicated in my second sentence.  The skip list is not strictly inferior in every metric in every situation, so it's *possible* it would be better for OP, yes.

Comment: I was just asking if you know that _any_ operations on `ConcurrentSkipListMap` are faster than CHM?

Comment: If the number of threads altering the map greatly exceeds the concurrency level of the CHM, the skip list would be expected to pull ahead of it.  (Or if the way it's used and the way hashCode is implemented is just causing lots of arguing over the same segments)  Readers in a CHM, while they also don't "normally" lock, will in fact lock the segment if it's churning so fast they can't get a clean read. In the skiplist they would only block on what they want, not an entire segment.  Increasing the concurrency level is not free, takes more memory, impacts bulk operations.

Comment: e.g., the `containsValue` method could be forced to contend for the lock of each individual segment as it works its way through them looking for values, if there is overwhelming write frequency.

Comment: I was curious if you have any evidence to back up the claim.  It's interesting theory.  I might write some code to check it out to see if I can see any difference.